# Forward Referencing or Declaration in C++

Tags: c++, syntax, forward-declaration

How do I do forward referencing / declaration in C++ to avoid circular header file references?

I have the #ifndef guard in the header file, yet memory tells me I need this forward referencing thing - which i've used before >< but can't remember how.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You predeclare the class without including it.  For example:

```
//#include "Foo.h" // including Foo.h causes circular reference
class Foo;

class Bar
{
...
};
```

Comment: Also to note in this case: class Bar cannot contain a class Foo, but it can have a pointer to a class Foo.

Comment: Also note that the formal return type of functions can be of the forward declared type.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the correct term for what you are talking about is "forward declaration".  "Forward referencing" would be a bit confusing.

Answer (score -2):

You won't get circular header files references if you have #ifndef guards.  That's the point.

Forward referencing is used to avoid #include(ing) header files for objects you use only by pointer or reference.  However, in this case you are not solving a circular reference problem, you're just practicing good design and decoupling the .h file from details it doesn't need to know.

Comment: That's not accurate. forward referencing could replace the need for an #include and thus eliminating the need for an #include circle.

Comment: I agree that if you didn't have #ifndef guards, you might (sloppily) try to manage all your circular header dependencies by using forward declarations, however the OP said he DID have header guards.