# Resolving circular dependency in the State Pattern with C++

Tags: c++, design-patterns

I'm trying to implement a State Pattern in C++, but have problems with the circular dependency. I have read other related material here - unfortunately it didn't help me. I don't have a lot of experience with C++, so bear with me.
The following code is developed on a Ubuntu 10.10 machine in Eclipse Helios CDT:

**ConcreteSystem.h**

```
#ifndef CONCRETESYSTEM_H_
#define CONCRETESYSTEM_H_

class SystemState;

class ConcreteSystem {
public:
    ConcreteSystem();
    void SelfTestFailed();
    void Restart();
private:
    friend class SystemState;
    SystemState *currentState;
    void ChangeState(SystemState *state);
};

#endif /* CONCRETESYSTEM_H_ */
```

**ConcreteSystem.cpp**

```
#include "ConcreteSystem.h"
#include "SystemState.h"

ConcreteSystem::ConcreteSystem() {
    currentState = SelfTest::GetInstance();
}

void ConcreteSystem::SelfTestFailed() {
    currentState->SelfTestFailed(this);
}

void ConcreteSystem::Restart() {
    currentState->Restart(this);
}

void ConcreteSystem::ChangeState(SystemState *state){
    currentState = state;
}
```

**SystemState.h**

```
#ifndef SYSTEMSTATE_H_
#define SYSTEMSTATE_H_

class ConcreteSystem;

class SystemState {
public:
    virtual void Restart(ConcreteSystem *cs);
    virtual void SelfTestFailed(ConcreteSystem *cs);
protected:
    virtual void ChangeState(ConcreteSystem *cs, SystemState *state);
};

#endif /* SYSTEMSTATE_H_ */
```

**SystemState.cpp**

```
#include "SystemState.h"
#include "ConcreteSystem.h"

void SystemState::Restart(ConcreteSystem *cs) {

}

void SystemState::SelfTestFailed(ConcreteSystem *cs) {

}


void SystemState::ChangeState(ConcreteSystem *cs, SystemState *state) {
    cs->ChangeState(state);
}
```

**SelfTest.h**

```
#ifndef SELFTEST_H_
#define SELFTEST_H_

#include "SystemState.h"


class SelfTest : public SystemState {
public:
    SelfTest();
    void SelfTestFailed(ConcreteSystem* cs);
    static SystemState* GetInstance();
private:
    static SystemState* instance;
};

#endif /* SELFTEST_H_ */
```

**SelfTest.cpp**

```
#include "SelfTest.h"
#include "Failure.h"

SystemState* SelfTest::instance = 0;

SelfTest::SelfTest() {

}

void SelfTest::SelfTestFailed(ConcreteSystem *cs) {
    ChangeState(cs, Failure::GetInstance());
}

SystemState* SelfTest::GetInstance() {
    if (instance == 0) {
        instance = new SelfTest();
    }
    return instance;
}
```

**Failure.h**

```
#ifndef FAILURE_H_
#define FAILURE_H_

#include "SystemState.h"

class SelfTest;

class Failure : public SystemState {
public:
    Failure();
    void Restart(ConcreteSystem* t);
    static SystemState* GetInstance();
private:
    static SystemState* instance;
};

#endif /* FAILURE_H_ */
```

**Failure.cpp**

```
#include "Failure.h"
#include "SelfTest.h"

SystemState* Failure::instance = 0;

Failure::Failure() {

}

void Failure::Restart(ConcreteSystem* t) {
    ChangeState(t, SelfTest::GetInstance());
}

SystemState* Failure::GetInstance() {
    if (instance == 0) {
        instance = new Failure();
    }
    return instance;
}
```

I have problem with the includes, which gives me some weird compiler errors. Anyone with a good solution to this problem?

Comment: If you have circular dependencies, you should learn about *forward declarations*. The chosen answer here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/553682/when-to-use-forward-declaration) is an excellent writeup of the topic.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/183898/forward-referencing-or-declaration-in-c

Comment: You need to post the exact errors you get. Also, please try to post the *minimum* amount of source code that reproduces your problem.

Comment: I tried to take the minimum of code, but I think it is necessary have to whole pattern represented.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the looks of the code you've posted, you'll have classes being redefined. Looking at your `Failure.cpp` file, you have:

```
#include "Failure.h"
#include "SelfTest.h"
```

Which will include both of those files, and each of those files include the `SystemState.h` file. Since the `SystemState.h` file is included more than once, it tries to redefine the `SystemState` class. At the top of each of your header files, you should do something like this:

```
// SystemState.h
#ifndef SystemState_h
#define SystemState_h
.. class definition ..
#endif // close the if statement from above.
```

As an aside on the design, I think it's bad form for the states to know about each other - use your `ConcreteSystem` as a state controller and then base the state on the return value of the last state operation.

Also, if you're relatively inexperienced with C++, I would recommend [looking at this](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/#table-of-contents) as a great source of learning material (in addition to StackOverflow, of course!).

Comment: The #ifndef / #define / #endif technique is called a *header guard*.

Comment: @Emile Cormier: Thanks, I couldn't remember the name

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried the header guard, but the problem lies the multi-inclusion to gain access to its other classes. My pattern is based on the GoF State Pattern, [like this website](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/38962/State-Design-Pattern.aspx?msg=3160835), so I need to access them.

Comment: Can you please post the compiler errors you're getting as part of your question? It will help everyone help you :)

Comment: I get an error in SystemState.h:15 ‘ConcreteSystem’ has not been declared.

Comment: In the declaration of SystemState::Restart, you say `virtual void Restart(class ConcreteSystem* cs);` where you should really have `virtual void Restart(ConcreteSystem* cs);`

Comment: I have corrected that now. I also have edited post, to my current version, which gives two types of error. In the _Failure.cpp: undefined reference to Failure::instance_ in GetInstance() and in the SelfTest.cpp _undefined reference to SelfTest::instance_.

Comment: You need to define the variables in your .cpp files. For example, in Failure.cpp, under your includes, put `SystemState* Failure::instance = 0;`. This will actually initialize the value to something. See http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/ctors.html#faq-10.12 (found from the link in my answer).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, that was exactly the problem. I have updated the code with by last modifications, and it seems to work smoothly now!

Comment: No problem! Since the code you've posted now works, you should probably close it up.